# Implement sqlite3.wasm Web Assembly in my Older AngularJS Solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, webassembly

I need to implement a *persistent* Sqlite3 database in my older AngularJS solution. So far, I've managed to implement a transient Sqlite3 database, but have not successfully implemented the persistent database.

I have been successful at implementing a transient database by using this page: [A Database in your Browser in sqlite3 Steps](https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/demo-123.md)

I have followed the instructions at this page: [SQLite Wasm in the browser backed by the Origin Private File System](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sqlite-wasm-in-the-browser-backed-by-the-origin-private-file-system) and get hung up with the `import` statement. I just get a Javascript console error that indicates it no longer recognizes the page. In lieu of the `import` statement, I have tried the following that I found at [Loading and running WebAssembly code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running)

```
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("/js/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.wasm"), someKindOfObject).then(
        (results) => {
            alert("Here we are");
            // Do something with the results!
        }
    );
```

However, I have no idea what I should use for `someKindOfObject` in the above snippet.

How do I correctly import/instantiate sqlite3.wasm in my AngularJS application so I can access a persistent database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const loadSQLiteWASM = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('path/to/sqlite3.wasm');
      const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const sqlite3 = await initSqlJs({ locateFile: () => 'path/to/sqlite3.wasm' });
      const db = new sqlite3.Database();
db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name demoTbl)');

    };
    
    loadSQLiteWASM();
```

you can check out this that i have create an demo